# Do I need a custom memory allocator?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I'm currently developing a cache server which for its own nature uses a lot of [RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory) (I'm testing it on a server with a lot of [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) traffic and both a [WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) and a custom web application using it to cache data in memory).

The server obviously performs a lot of malloc/realloc/free operations which are expensive, so I was wondering if I should use a custom memory allocator, maybe something which preallocates a big "memory pool" at the beginning and then using it to give free "pieces" of the requested size when a malloc/realloc is performed, and flagging them as freed when a free is called.

Am I taking the right path or don't I really need such a thing? Is there an allocator like that or do I have to code one of my own?

**Important notes:**

- The server is **single-threaded** (using multiplexing), so I don't
  need allocators with high performance grades in multi-threading
  applications (such as **jemalloc**, which as far as I understood is
  just as good as the normal malloc in single-threaded applications...
  Correct me if I'm wrong, please).
- Before you ask/suggest, I've already used [Valgrind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind) to remove every
  possible memory leak. I just need to optimize, not to fix.
- Memory fragmentation is a problem, so I should use an approach to optimize this too.
- Using an appropriate configuration directive, the user can set the
  maximum usable memory from the server, so that's why a preallocated
  fixed memory pool came to my mind.
- I don't have performance problems; I'm developing this just for fun and curiosity. I like to learn and experiment with new programming techniques.
- And yes, I've used callgrind, and malloc is one of the most expensive operations.

Comment: "Do i need a custom memory allocator?" If you have to ask, the answer is "No."

Comment: Since you have valgrind, have you used callgrind to determine if malloc() really is a bottleneck?  The malloc() in modern compilers generally isn't the dog it used to be, so there may be some other reason for your performance problems.

Comment: What would make your version of `malloc`/`realloc`/`free` inherently less expensive than the normal ones, especially if you still need to deal with memory fragmentation?

Comment: i never said i have performance problems, i was just wondering if i can optimize the server :) and yes, malloc was one of the most expensive operations during my tests

Comment: If you don't have performance problems, why fix what isn't broken?

Comment: because i'm developing this just for fun and curiosity, i like to learn and experiment new programming techniques, so ... why not? :)

Comment: That's fine, but you imply the opposite with the title you have. "Do I need..." is a practicality-based question ("well, what are your requirements?"), but with for-fun stuff the answer is always, "well, if you want to and feel like doing so." I hope that clarifies why others and myself are commenting in the fashion we are. If this is for fun and you already want to do it, don't ask if you *need* to (you need to so you can satisfy your curiosity), ask *how* to. (Though such a question may be too broad.)

Comment: english is not my language, so i don't always express myself precisely ... with "do i need ..." i mean "would i gain some sort of performance boost from it?" and since i don't want to reinvent the wheel i'm asking if there's some memory management library :)

Comment: +1 to Kevin's comment. The answer to this question is basically always "no". Especially for single-threaded use, the basic dlmalloc algorithm which all modern allocators use is **unbeatable**.

Comment: @SimoneMargaritelli: No worries! The only way to answer these kinds of performance questions is to try things out and measure the results. And survey questions ("what allocators exist for XYZ?") are not suitable for SO, as it's too broad.

Comment: @R.. It's not unbeatable. It's certainly top-notch for the problem it solves: Implementing `malloc` and `free`, a.k.a. being everything to everyone. But if you know your memory use pattern and it's sufficiently uniform that another, simpler kind of allocator is sufficient (examples: a pool if you only need fixed-size blocks; a stack allocator if you only need FIFO behaviour) then an allocator specialized for that use case has a good shot at beating `*malloc` simply because it can make useful assumptions `*malloc` cannot make (and optimize accordingly).

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more clear. What I meant was that there is no more-optimal allocator with the same API as `malloc`/`free`.

Comment: @SimoneMargaritelli - write it, test it, compare with malloc and make the conclusion whether it was worth writing it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you said you don't have a performance problem, you don't need to do anything. Set that aside.

You need a foothold to get any kind of improvement, since `malloc` is really fast. Offhand I recall about 100-200 cycles, on Mac OS X from a few years ago. (But `free` can also take more time, which should show up in the profiling statistics.) Writing a better general-purpose allocator is essentially impossible, beyond skill and luck.

Patterns specific to your application can still expose opportunities, though. I've had luck with programs that free objects in roughly the same order as their creation.

1. Create some memory buckets.
2. `malloc` returns blocks from the buckets in linear fashion.
3. `free` marks blocks as unused. This may utilize a bitmap, a managed smart-pointer, or the like. For pure garbage collection, no explicit call is needed.
4. When the last bucket is full, sweep the last recently used one(s) but only check if *completely* empty.
5. If no empty bucket, make a new one.

This is a horrible strategy if there's *any* fragmentation but it can improve on plain `malloc` by a couple orders of magnitude, because scanning along a bucket until the end just takes 1-2 cycles instead of 100-200, and for little enough fragmentation you can always make the sweeps infrequent enough.

The one-in-a-million slow sweep also disqualifies this approach from many applications.

I don't know much about cache servers, but perhaps this approach would work for HTTP connection objects which are highly transient. You need to focus not on all of `malloc`, but the subset of allocations which incur the biggest cost in the most predictable pattern.